# Android ( Textview1.settext ) crashing app

Tags: android

here is my code the code it self works but am trying to add all the data to my  Textview1 with new line so it shows in this format

22:22 
13:44 
33:33 
xx:xx 
xx:xx

but app crashes because of this Textview1 code something am doing wrong.

```
private TextView textView1;
```

oncreate

```
textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

please tell me why my Textview1 is crashing app ?

```
            for(int j=0;j<hrefElements.size();j++)
            {
                //System.out.println("Links: "+links[j]);
                System.out.println("Title: "+title[j]);
                textView1.setText("SUBH: "+timee[j] +" \n");
                System.out.println("SUBH: "+timee[j]);
                System.out.println("DUHR: "+timee1[j]);
                System.out.println("ASR: "+timee2[j]);
                System.out.println("MAGHRIB: "+timee3[j]);
                System.out.println("ISHA: "+timee4[j]);








stacktracr error log

    Process: testtt.myapplication, PID: 22819
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6915)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1056)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17321)
            at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8009)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4841)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4673)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4648)
            at testtt.myapplication.MainActivity$JsoupAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:102)
            at testtt.myapplication.MainActivity$JsoupAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-14 03:45:04.741  22819-22819/testtt.myapplication E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {testtt.myapplication/testtt.myapplication.MainActivity}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {testtt.myapplication/testtt.myapplication.MainActivity}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3203)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3181)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: system.out.print  code is working am just trying to     print all them to Textview1 with new line

Comment: Post a complete stack trace of the exception from logcat.

Comment: post the whole doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original 
        thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

You are setting the text of the textview from a background thread. You have to do it on the main (UI) thread. Change your `AsyncTask` to simply build the string in `doInBackground()` and update the textview in `onPostExecute()` instead.

Comment: /@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            parsedHtmlNode.setText(htmlContentInStringFormat);
            textViewwww.setText("SUBH: "+timee[j] +" \n");               //      the timee[j]   shows  red
        }

Comment: @JeanLee I've explained what you need to do, but it's your code, you need to make the necessary changes. Read the documentation for AsyncTask, you can define it so `doInBackground()` returns a String that gets passed into `onPostExecute()`. Build the String in `doInBackground()`, then use it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Please i wasted 5 hours already cmon am new and am trying just stuck thats why sir

Comment: @JeanLee too many people come to StackOverflow expecting others to write code for them. We also are busy people and have things to do. I don't know anything about your code and have given you plenty of direction to make this change.

Comment: am getting all my time together rather then putting new line in them     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            parsedHtmlNode.setText(htmlContentInStringFormat);
            textViewwww.setText("\n"+amarrdatta+"\n");
        }

Comment: all time shows    xx:xx   xx:xx xx:xx  i want to add new line to them